# Working with spec\support\jasmine.json'

Tags: jasmine

I am reading the jasmine docs

Customize spec/support/jasmine.json to enumerate the source files and spec files you would like the Jasmine runner to include. You may use dir glob strings.

However, I cannot find the file path **spec\support\jasmine.json**

Inside of the node_module for jasmine only exists under this file structure

```
node_modules >> jasmine >> lib >> examples >> jasmine.json
```

Am I missing something very basic?  I did the install twice and got the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to run `jasmine init`, then the following file is created.
If it is not working, install jasmine globally `npm install -g jasmine`

Regards